# Prevent PDFsharp from saving an image file?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I have prevented my program from saving images downloaded as files. (They are saved in Image variables instead). However, my application is slowed down significantly because the PDFsharp libraries save the image files anyway before drawing them to the PDF document. This is done deep within a hierarchy of calls by its functions.

Is there a simple fix to get around this?

Comment: Did you do some measurements that show the impact? And I hope you made the tests with the Release build.

Comment: Images used in the PDF file will be embedded in the PDF file. This requires saving them. They are saved in the PDF file or PDF stream. They are not saved as separate image files in the local file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPEG images are simply copied into the PDF file, all other image formats have to be converted to the PDF format. AFAIK PDFsharp does not save the images to the local file system, however they are saved into a memory stream during the conversion.

There is a simple fix to get around this: write a better conversion and submit it to the PDFsharp team.

Answer (score -1):

I think PDFSharp always need to save first. It cannot handle byte image that will used to import an image. I recently encountered it when I also coded and used pdfsharp. My process is to save an image then import to code in pdfsharp. I have a part that I need to delete all temporary images.

Comment: You do not have to save images to a file. PDFsharp internally uses the Save() method to write the image to a MemoryStream. But user code can use Image objects in memory.